Adding raster metadata
I'm trying to write metadata into a raster file for QGIS so that it appears in the Metadata tab. When I write metadata for a .tiff file in QGIS using the menu options, the information isn't saved when I remove the file from the project and then re-add it:

It seems this information is saved in the project file, as mentioned in this QGIS Enhancement Proposal: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/91.
I'm looking for a solution similar to this one for layers: Python editing of QGIS layer metadata
but for rasters.
I know you can save metadata in a .qml file, but I need this metadata embedded in the file itself because it will be shared widely. Additionally, I understand that GeoPackage can store this information, but converting a 3-band raster in QGIS gives me an error. If there's a proper way to convert it, please let me know.
Here's what I've tried so far:
from osgeo import gdal

# Open the existing TIFF file
dataset = gdal.Open('file.tif', gdal.GA_Update)

# Read description from text file
with open('description.txt', 'r') as file:
    description = file.read()

metadata = {
    'Author': 'Your Name',
    'Date': '2024-10-14',
    'Description': description
}

dataset.SetMetadata(metadata)
dataset = None

This updates the information in the Information tab but doesn't affect the Metadata tab.
Any suggestions on how to correctly write metadata that shows up in the Metadata tab in QGIS?

The metadata that is saved into TIFF https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#metadata is different from the QGIS metadata https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#metadata. Saving the QGIS metadata into .qmd file is the correct way. The saved qmd metadata can be loaded with the same metadata button. If you are not happy with the metadata that is saved into a sidecar file then you must be content with the TIFF metadata.

Please describe the GeoPackage issue properly and make another question from it.
